# Return contours neatly - OpenCV/Java

Tags: java, opencv

I have this image below as a reference for studying a future project that I will create, using `findContours()`. I was successful in practically everything, but I had a problem and another question (which is not a problem, but can be improved). The problem is that the contours are not in the right order, as in the image, whose "H" should return first, "i" second, "n" third and so on. He returns to me, "niodHe". What am I missing from the code below? Or what should I add to fix this?

[image]

```
      Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\deskadmin\\Desktop\\CONSTRUCAO\\1.png");
      Mat original = image.clone();
      Mat imageHSV = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
      Mat imageBlurr = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
      Mat imageA = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_32F);
      Imgproc.cvtColor(image, imageHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
      Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageHSV, imageBlurr, new Size(5,5), 0);
      Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageBlurr, imageA, 255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,7, 5);

      List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
      Imgproc.findContours(imageA, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
      //Collections.sort(contours, Comparator.comparingDouble(Imgproc::contourArea));
      for(int i = 0, j = 2; i < (contours.size()-1); i++, j++){
         System.out.println("Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)): "+Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)));
       //if(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > 50 ){
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
         //if(rect.height < 100 & rect.height > 11){
          Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(0,0,255));
          Mat roi = original.submat(rect);
          Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\deskadmin\\Desktop\\CONSTRUCAO\\"+j+".png",roi);
         //}else if (rect.height >= 100){
          //Mat roi = image.submat(rect);
          //Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\deskadmin\\Desktop\\CONSTRUCAO\\marcacao.png",roi);
          //}
       //}
      }
```

Comment: *hinode* no Stackoverflow... tirou o dia para trollar a galera?!

Comment: Pior que não, foi a melhor imagem que achei na net no dia que comecei a estudar o `findContours()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findContours()` processes the image from the **bottom to the top** AND **right to the left**, if I'm not mistaken.

Simply create a bounding box around each contour and add them to a list.

Later, sort them by using their `x,y` position and you'll have the letters in the order that you would like to read them.

Comment: In fact, I already tried that. But it didn't work out very well. I'm using `Collections.sort (contours, Comparator.comparingDouble (Imgproc :: contourArea));` to sort this out. Without this code it returns me in the following form: "ieodHn".
`Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 151.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 250.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 175.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 217.0
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 199.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 149.0`

Comment: With this code, it returns me as i put it in the question, "niodHe". `Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 149.0
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 151.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 175.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 199.5
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 217.0
Imgproc.contourArea (contours.get (i)): 250.5`. I believe he is not processing the image as you said. Because he understands that the first letter is "n" and not "H", as it should be, or, otherwise, "e", as you said.

Comment: There is no universal answer using only img processing techniques. The rotation of the text in the image will break your sorting algorithm. For some rotations it will work great, for some others... nope. The ideal solution would be to use an OCR library to spit the text for you. Perhaps something like Tesseract.

Comment: Actually, after i stopped to analyze my code. I was not sorting by the x or y axis. It was sorting by `contourArea()`. I updated my code the way you indicated and managed to solve my problem, thank you very much!